# How to fix my recursive code? out of bound error

Tags: matlab

```
function res=evalpolinomio(p1,x)
  [n,m]=size(p1);
  if n==0
    res=0
  else 
    res=p1(1)*x^(p1(1,2))+evalpolinomio(p1(2:n),x)
  endif
endfunction
```

error: p1(1): out of bound 0
error: called from
evalpolinomio at line 6 column 8
someone know what is the problem here?
i want to write a script that can evaluate a polynomy, polynomy is writed like p1=[a,2;b,1;c,0]=ax^2+bx+c

Answer (score 1):

if `n==1` you call `evalpolinomio(p1(2:n),x)` with `p1(2:1)` which is an empty array of size `1x0`. As you only check the first size (instead of using `isempty`) the if condition jumps to else. Then, inside, you call  `p1(1)` which errors.

Comment: As this looks like homework (otherwise no one should write a recursive function for this task) I will not fix it, but just let OP know what is wrong with their code.

Comment: thanks for answer, i fix it, but the problem now is that the result is not the expected value, if i run evalpolinomio(p1,2) on polynomy p1=[1,5;3,4;2,3;4,2;3,1;2,0],result is 44 but expected result is 110

Comment: Well, try to debug your code! run it step by step , to see how the values change

Comment: @GonzaloSimchuk consider accepting it as valid.